# How to achieve level 3 div with javascript and apply styling

Tags: javascript

Hello I would like to reach a level 3 div and change the style of this div
in my example I would therefore like to be able to apply disply:none on style color red
to make the word Warning invisible

```
<div id="Zone">
  <div class="MR-Widget ">
    <div class="Title"> </div>
    <div class="Errors" style="display: none"></div>
    <div class="Content">
      <div class="search"> </div>
      <div class="resultat" style="width: 120px;"></div>
      <div class="MR" id="Lock" style="display: none;"> </div>
      <div style="color: red"> Warning </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select 3rd level div:

```js
document.querySelector('#Zone > div > div > div')
```

Now the problem is you have 4 div at 3rd level. So needed to select all and check style color. That gives:

```js
const warningNone = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#Zone > div > div > div')).forEach(el => {
    if (el) {
      if (el.style.color === 'red') {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  })
}
window.addEventListener('load', warningNone);
```

```html
<div id="Zone">
  <div class="MR-Widget ">
    <div class="Title"> </div>
    <div class="Errors" style="display: none"></div>
    <div class="Content">
      <div class="search"> </div>
      <div class="resultat" style="width: 120px;"></div>
      <div class="MR" id="Lock" style="display: none;"> </div>
      <div style="color: red"> Warning </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I modified the snippet to check the >div>div>div existence

By the way, I put the function to be fired when document loaded, otherwise your red will not apply

3...

try to split the query line in 2:

```js
const warningNone = () => {
        const els = document.querySelectorAll('#Zone > div > div > div');
        els.forEach(el => {
            if (el.style.color === 'red') {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
        })
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', warningNone);
```

now in dev tools check which line fire the error